# Optimize SHA256 checking in php

Tags: php, optimization, cycle, sha256, sha

I have `SHA256` hash text, and i know original text is a string and consist of **0-9 numbers** and **letters a-z, A-Z**  that is in **range (000000-ZZZZZZ)**.

This code checks all possible options, and returns the original text
This code working long time **(for example if string length is 5 then it works 30 minutes, for case if length 6 it works 30*62 minutes )** and i think this is not best solution for this case.
Please help optimize it.

```
    $count=0;
    $start_date =microtime(true); 

$s=array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
for($g=0;$g<62;$g++)
{
    for($h=0;$h<62;$h++)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<62;$i++)
        {
            for($j=0;$j<62;$j++)
            {
                for($k=0;$k<62;$k++)
                {
                    for($l=0;$l<62;$l++)
                    {
                        $count++;
                        if (hash("sha256",$s[$g].$s[$h].$s[$i].$s[$j].$s[$k].$s[$l])=='0a482c589594109cea209233a1f3bfa51f8a52e4534c40e9511c6030ee0f594a')// string is ZZZZZZ
                        {
                            echo $s[$g].$s[$h].$s[$i].$s[$j].$s[$k].$s[$l]."<br/>";
                            echo $count."<br/>";
                            $end_date =microtime(true);
                            echo ($end_date-$start_date)/60;
                            break(6);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to break SHA256 encryption?

Comment: Also known as a brute forcing.

Comment: Yes, that is what it looks like. Brute force attacks are usually used in malicious acts. You won't find help here.

Comment: Guess this just demonstrates why people should use `password_hash()` and also to avoid sites that dont allow you to increase your entropy by using a longer password

Comment: People typically use dictionaries of commonly used texts along with variation/permutation rules instead of pure brute-force. Either way it won't help you for texts which are longer than a few characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't optimize it to break `0-9a-zA-Z` fastest. Of course You can optimize this code a little (also change PHP for Python or something faster), but only gave You boost from 30 minutes to 10 minutes for 5 chars. 6 chars needs much about 6 hours. And 7 chars measured in days. 8 chars in years etc. **It's impossible to do it faster.**

You should know that an sha256 is a method of encryption, that in assumption do not allow to decrypt, that's the purpose of this method. Unfortunately (fortunately for You), in the case of short strings it's possible to decrypt in short time.

Comment: this is not best solution for me, i want do this for sting who length is 10

Comment: 10 length? Oh, just about 10 000 years. Good luck ;)

Comment: That's why i want to find an optimal solution

Comment: 10 000 years is **optimal** solution